# TypeAhead does not select node within picker

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Valid for ExtJS 4.1.3

We have a Combo that is configured like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 450,
    emptyText: 'Customer...',
    hideLabel: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    store: Select,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    valueField: 'Id',
    displayField: 'Name',
    triggerAction: 'all'
}
```

If we begin to type something into the combo before the picker was rendered for the first time typeAhead managed to find the appropriate record but cannot select it. If we open the picker first by clicking the trigger all works well.

Within debugging I managed to see that typeAhead cannot find the node for the record even while I can see the picker and the node (just still masked with loading).

Sidenote: We are not able to upgrade the version.

Can this be fixed in some way?

Any Help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "manages to find the record but cannot select it"?

Comment: @rixo I set a breakpoint within the onTypeAhead method of the combo and looked at each value step by step. All works fine expect getNode(record) in the line boundList.highlightItem(boundList.getNode(record)); which returned null which I don't understand cause I saw the list and the item. As mentioned the list was still masked but all items where there.

Comment: @rixo to be more precise getNodeByRecord encounter 0 for this.all.elements

Comment: is store loaded automatically? why do you need a trigger button? what does it do?

Comment: @dbrin The store is loaded by the combo and the button is required because we cannot force hour customer to type he may also want to select a value from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I was able to reproduce your problem with 4.1.1a (I don't have a 4.1.3 at hand), but I did get the type ahead to fail before the first load. I was able to work around it by triggering type ahead after the store has loaded:

```
combo.getStore().on({
    load: {
        single: true,
        fn: function() {
            combo.onTypeAhead();
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure if that can be helpful in your case.

If I were you and if practicable in your case, I would turn that combo box to `queryMode: local`, have the server send all the data at once, and be done with it. Plus the combo will be super reactive!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is as we feared. Not exactly but basically our workarounds are the same as yours. Even if this is not what we hoped to hear :( Anyway, again thanks for the quick response!